# How to find what's hogging what resources?

Tags: performance, monitoring, profiling, resources

I've found lots of similar questions, but nothing that's exactly right.

I'm trying to figure out what's making one server run slower than another.  I'm hoping for something that would say something like what resources are being used the most (I/O, ram, cpu, chickens) and what processes are using those resources in significant amounts.

I don't just want to start throwing solutions at it to see what will stick.  I want metrics of some kind.  I don't want to sit there with top, iotop, nettop & chickentop open, scribbling in a notebook.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `topas`. This will give you a much better picture of what you are trying to see. You can also use `nmon`, as `nmon` has various switches which you can use to run it in daemon mode and write log file. The sampling interval is configurable. This output can be analysed with "nmon analyzer", another free tool downloadable on the IBM freeware webpage for AIX. But if you do not want to install "nmon analyzer" you have less choice other than analyzing the log files yourself. Large scale systems have tools such as Foglight etc. installed which gives you more comprehensive reporting capabilities and alerting facilities.